# Use ActiveX in invisible C++Builder application

Tags: activex, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm working on a C++Builder application that uses an ActiveX control to perform some background work. If I run the app visibly, it works fine. But when when I run it invisibly (done by setting `Application->ShowMainForm = false` during startup), the ActiveX control does not behave the same. ActiveX methods that return immediately work fine, but a method that does background work does not work, no progress is made.

What can be done to make ActiveX controls behave normally, and let them perform background tasks, when the application is invisible?

As a test, I have created a small C# .NET project in Visual Studio, and there the same ActiveX control works fine in invisible mode (but not in C++Builder).

Comment: There is really nothing special about `Application->ShowMainForm = false`, it merely hides the `MainForm` from appearing onscreen when `Application->Run()` is called.  The `MainForm` window still exists, and the main message loop still runs. So there is no reason for your ActiveX control to not work, unless it requires a non-hidden parent window. But then your C# test would fail under similar conditions. So there has to be another factor at play that you have not described.

Comment: If I had to guess, your `MainForm` is likely not creating its `HWND` at all since you are not showing it visually. Try calling `Application->MainForm->HandleNeeded()` before `Application->Run()`. Or, get rid of `Application->ShowMainForm = false` and instead set the `MainForm` to minimize itself. Or, just move the `MainForm` off-screen.

Comment: Calling ``HandleNeeded()`` on the form proved not needed in my case, but calling it on the control itself fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Calling HandleNeeded() on the ActiveX control in the form constructor fixed the problem.

```
TForm1::TForm1()
{
    control1->HandleNeeded();
}
```

Apparently, some ActiveX controls need a window handle to function properly, and this handle is not created automatically when it is hidden.